# For an id in multiple rows find if values exists in pandas

Tags: pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
d = {'id':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','d','d','d'],
 'seg':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
 'type':['y','y','y','z','z','z','y1','y1','z','z','z','y2']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I am trying to filter id based on the following conditions:

1. only `z`
2. only `y`
3. both `y` and `z`

For first and second condition I can do the following:

```
df_y = df.loc[df['type'].str.contains('y')]
df_z = df.loc[df['type'] == 'z']
```

I can then take `unique` for id column.

How can I check if both `y` and `z` exist in `type` column for the same id?

Outputs:

```
df_y 

id
a
c
d

df_z 

id
b
```

Required outputs:

```
df_y

id
a

df_z

id
b

df_y_z

id
c
d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

```
df[df.groupby('id')['type']\
     .transform(lambda x: x[x.str.contains('y|z')].nunique()) == 2]
```

Output:

```
   id  seg type
6   c    1   y1
7   c    2   y1
8   c    3    z
9   d    1    z
10  d    2    z
11  d    3   y2
```

Note: you can use contains or startwith if you just want those types that start with y or z.

---

IIUC, to get df_y_z, first filter your dataframe down to only rows with y or z if you have more types, then groupby id, and count the number of unique types if equal to 2 then you have groups with both y and z:

```
df.loc[df.query('type in ["y","z"]').groupby('id')['type'].transform('nunique') == 2]
```

Output:

```
   id  seg type
6   c    1    y
7   c    2    y
8   c    3    z
9   d    1    z
10  d    2    z
11  d    3    y
```

Comment: `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).` Getting this error

Answer (score 2):

We can do `crosstab` + `dot`

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.id,df.type).ne(0)
s.dot(s.columns)
Out[277]: 
id
a     y
b     z
c    yz
d    yz
dtype: object
```

Comment: I am having 5 types of values in my dataframe and its returning True or False matrix when I use crosstab. I have updated my dataframe input with how i am handling those multiple values. Please check.

Comment: @y1 and y2 is equal to y ?

Comment: they are part of same group `y`. Basically all i care about is `z` vs others. But I want to make sure I find those ids which are part of both groups.